# Why eclipse is not recognising webdriver.gecko.driver

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, geckodriver

I'm learning selenium testing in eclipse, just started. I am trying to open firefox browser using the script . Using firefox 51 and selenium-java-3.1.0.
I pasted geckodriver-v0.14.0-win64 exe file in required location and used following code:[image: eclipse is showing error] eclipse is showing error with webdriver.gecko.driver  as shown in the screenshot. What could be the problem? I have added all the required jar files. from selenium 3.1.0 and also the selenium server standalone jar file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks you are copied code from some where else.

All the strings in your program aren't surrounded by double quotes("). The double quotes you are seeing are actually called as **curly double quotes**. So, I suggest you manually type double quote(").

Answer (score 1):

I used a chrome driver instead of a firefox driver. Anyway, I would like to suggest you can create a method for your driver initialization and specify the path like this. also it is well easy to use always chrome for testing!

public void setUpTest() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\Users\purushotha\eclipse-workspace\SeleniumJavaFramework1\drivers\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe");

```
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
}
```